# Will emacs/vi ever be able to implement Intellisense/Refactorings as well as Visual Studio and Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, visual-studio, emacs, vi

I love the old school editors because they enable users to absolutely *fly* through their code, editing almost as fast as they can think.

However, they suck balls at awareness of their environment, lacking robust implementations of features like Intellisense (pre-emptive strike: no, there really isn't an intellisense implementation in emacs that is trivial to install and doesn't suck) and common refactorings (pre-emptive strike #2: "global search and replace" does not a refactoring tool make). (i.e. It would be nice to be able to use nothing but vim to develop in .Net, but at the moment it is an ill-conceived undertaking at best).

I love Visual Studio/Eclipse/XCode because they are so integrated with their environments that I almost never need to look up API documentation, and can refactor fearlessly.

However, they suck balls at basic text manipulation and macros (relative to vi/emacs), are not available on all platforms (with exception of Eclipse), are likely either going to change nontrivially or perhaps just not be around in the next 10-20 years, and most importantly, are unable to run tetris.

Will we ever see the day when emacs or vi will be able to be as tightly integrated with .Net, Java and Objective-C projects as Visual Studio, Eclipse and XCode?

If not, is it because of proprietary concerns? (i.e. would require emacs to ship with a copy of the .Net framework)? Or is it just because at the moment our team doesn't have the manpower?

Comment: Eclipse is not available on all platforms.

Comment: There are many tools to come close or even better. Cedet being a good example. Personally I think that if you remove intellisense it makes you more familiar with the code which is a good thing in the long run. Also those features tend to hog computer resources in the background to generate completions and such. The one thing though is that they're NOT meant to be tightly integrated so that they can be general editors.

Comment: @Jesus (always wanted to have a legit reason to type that) - Eh, while I appreciate your taking the time out to respond, and it's a very intelligent, well-thought-out comment, it strikes me as being akin to the old argument that if I attach a steak knife to my steering wheel pointing at my chest, it will make me a better driver.

Comment: @Jordan I can see your point that's why there are packages like Cedet but the main reason you don't get .NET support is because .NET is relatively new on unix systems so development hasnt gone into it very much although there are major modes out there for c# (which I used at my last job, the only guy in the company who didnt need 16gb of RAM to open the project :P) and many other non-mainstream supported languages. Visual studio is also a lot more than a text editor (not in the Emacs sense where it's an OS almost). I find it's easier to refactor in Emacs than in VS but thats just me.

Comment: @Jesus - also, regardless of the fact that they are not meant to be tightly integrated with certain languages, the fact is that such integration is highly valuable to users. Could it be an absolute impossibility that you have an editor that is great at general editing but also able to know its way around the .Net or Java environment when you load a project of that type as well? (ie java-mode would be enormous, but you could choose not to have it)

Comment: @Jordan In the unix world that would be considered bloat though. Emacs is no longer the default text editor (usually vi and nano) because it has grown too large to distribute on bare systems (most anyway, some still have it). But at the same time it does offer flexibility to do those things you say, you can find MANY things out there for java and .net autocompletion and intellisense and even project management. It's not included by default but it does exist :P You trade default features for customization and in the end being able to do what you want is more invaluable.

Comment: @Jesus - not bloat; if emacs could be as tightly integrated with .net as Visual Studio is, there is no way you would include csharp-mode by default.

Comment: @Jordan But that would require emacs to come with those features by default which means more code and other things in general. The features you talk about DO exist they just happen to be separate elisp files that people have developed or are available in the forms of separate packages, there's no reason for it to come tightly coupled with .net features or java if you can find what you want. It's always easier to add things than to remove and Emacs is still trying to be lightweight.

Comment: @Jesus - I completely disagree with the notion that there are packages you can add to emacs that make it just as useful as Visual Studio for working with .Net. In my opinion there is nothing for emacs even remotely close to being as good as VS's Intellisense, Cedet or otherwise.

Comment: @Jordan Cedet + auto-complete.el, and add a dictionary for auto-complete that contains some .Net specifics and you've got something usable. And of course you're not going to get something as complete because Visual Studio was made specifically for that.

Comment: For this to be a fair question, you really need to tell us what *size* balls you've tested the suction of various IDEs on.

Comment: One other answer is simple: companies like Apple and Microsoft have a strong incentive to make you use their IDE since it makes it less likely you'll write software for the competitor (i.e. to try and "lock you in").  So they have a lot more resources than we can ever hope to have to develop those tools.

Answer (score 2):

Why not load a Vi / Emacs emulator into Visual Studio / Eclipse and get the best of both worlds?

There are free versions of both for Visual Studio 2010 and above.

- [VsVim - Free](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/59ca71b3-a4a3-46ca-8fe1-0e90e3f79329)
- [Emacs Emulator - Free](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/09dc58c4-6f47-413a-9176-742be7463f92/)
- [ViEmu - License Fee, works prior to VS 2010](http://www.viemu.com/)

Eclipse has some as well.

- [Vrapper](http://vrapper.sourceforge.net/home/)

Comment: Are the emulators good enough to be satisfactory.  Does the vi emulator support "."?  Can the emacs emulator be configured through Lisp?

Comment: A while ago I acquiesced to this being the "least bad" solution, but it's not ideal. While it might not officially Suck Balls, it still kinda sucks. (e.g. Emacs emulation in Visual Studio has a bunch of funky bugs and copy/paste from outside programs doesn't work, all of which are unfixable b/c it's not open source, blah blah blah...) But yes, you are correct nevertheless :)

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen VsVim and ViEmu both support `.` and macros. They're fairly good implementations.  In general ViEmu has a greater set of features but VsVim is free to try.  Caveat: I'm the primary author of VsVim so I'm heavily biased :)

Comment: The problem with this approach is that the power of Emacs does not come from its keybindings, but from the power of the Elisp engine which you can use to easily bend the editor to your will. Emulating the keybindings is worthless in itself. I'm an emacs power user and I change lot of the default keybindings. They are not the reason I use emacs.

Comment: @Tom i'm a vim user so it's hard for me to comment intelligently on Emacs. But I've heard similar frustration from other Emacs users.  It would be nice if the emulator could be extended to support such an environment

Answer (score 1):

See [eclim](http://eclim.org/) which provides Eclipse features for Emacs/Vim, so you can work in your favorite editor while having intelligent completion and other features supported by an Eclipse backend.

If we don't have the manpower to implement these features natively then the best we can do is to utilize the features implemented by others.

Answer (score 1):

I think a significant part of the reason is technical and is due to Elisp: Elisp is very slow, and it lacks libraries.  A good IDE requires a good parser, various auxiliary data-structures, and needs to be fast (e.g. parsing many files).